# How to create Universal Link to Facebook?

Tags: deep-linking, ios-universal-links

Because iOS 9.2 broke the ability use Javascript, I'm trying to do this with a method that works. I'm attempting to create a link that:

**A**: If the user has Facebook App, open Facebook App

**B**: If the user doesn't have Facebook, open facebook.com

From what I can tell you can only create Universal Links for your own apps because you need to know the bundle identifier, etc. and obviously I don't know Facebook's

Comment: have you went through this thread ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42083226/how-to-implement-ios-app-link-facebook-functionality-in-swift-3

Comment: That is for swift. Looking for a javascript/php solution.